# why is this simple FOR LOOP in my Linux bash not working?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to do a simple for loop in a UNIX script (bash).

Here's my script:

```
for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

I was expecting this for output ...

```
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
```

... but I get this ...

```
Welcome {1..3} times
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not running it in bash.

Comment: There is a setopt to enable/disable curly expansion like that: `set -o braceexpand`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Pretty sure I am; a 'ps -p $$' shows me one process named 'bash'.

Comment: @bishop Thx, is that something I can add to the shell script before the for statement, or do I have to run that before the script is run?

Comment: You can add it before the `for`, or put it in your `.bashrc`.  Let me know if this solved your issue and, if so, I'll answer properly.

Comment: You can use `for i in $(seq 3)` instead.

Answer (score 19):

You didn't mention how you were executing your script and that can make a difference.  Suppose we have a script:

```
$ cat welcome.sh
for i in {1..3}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
echo "\n"
```

Observe the following three invocations of welcome.sh from a bash shell:

```
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11509 pts/25   00:00:00 bash
$ source welcome.sh
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times

$ bash welcome.sh
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times

$ sh welcome.sh
Welcome {1..3} times
```

The last one fails because, on my system, `sh` defaults to `dash`, not `bash`.  This is true, for example, for any modern Debian/Ubuntu-derived system.

Comment: See OP's comment. This seems very unlikely to be the right the answer, unless OP ran it with `sh` (definitely not the right answer if he ran `ps -p $$` from inside the script)

Comment: @BroSlow While you might be right, he did not state that he ran `ps -p $$` "from inside the script" and there are strong indications that he didn't.

Comment: This is a good reminder that `bash`, when invoked as "sh", *silently* drops into compatibility mode.

Comment: @pushpen.paul If you want to invoke a shell script as `./welcome.sh`, it is best practice to add, as the first line of the script, a shebang line such as `#!/bin/bash` that specifies which shell (or other program) you want to have execute the script.  If you want to execute as `./welcome.sh`, it is also necessary that the script have the _execute_ bit set: `chmod +x ./welcome.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

Moving my comment to formal answer:

```
set -o braceexpand
```

That enables `{x..y}` style (amongst other kinds of) expansion.  If you want it permanently, add it to your `.bashrc`.  If you want it temporarily, you can "bracket" your code:

```
set -o braceexpand  # enable brace expansion
echo {1..3}         # or whatever your command is
set +o braceexpand  # disable it
```

Frankly I think the code overhead of that on/off approach isn't worth it, and I always add brace expansion to my `.bashrc`.

Finally, [here's an excellent discussion of brace expansion ins and outs.](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)

Answer (score 2):

Several things to try:

- Run your script with bash as a prefix. `bash myscript.sh` instead of simply `myscript.sh`. This will guarantee you're running under BASH.
- Run `set -o` and see if *braceexpansion* is set to *on*. If not, run `set -o braceexpand` and see if that fixes your problem.

You can test for whether *braceexpand* is on or off with the `-o` *test*.

```
if [[ -o braceexpand ]]
then
    echo "Brace expand is on"
else
    echo "It is off"
fi
```

You can use this to test the state of *braceexpand*, so you can return it to its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I changed the shebang from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score -2):

Your script is not facing any type of error. I have faced the same problem and the simple solution is that you have not given it the permission to execute so you can do so:

```
chmod +x nameofyourscript.sh
```

and then run it like this

```
./nameofyourscript.sh
```